# Copying Values immediately based on other cell Values

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sheets-addons

I am collecting data from Google Form into a Google Sheet, in a **Form Responses** Sheet it has a **column R** that cell value changes (as the form responses can be editable), and the values can be Pending, Approved or Rejected. There is another **column Y** and this field also changes frequently.

Whenever cell value in **col R** changes to **Approved**, I need immediately copy the value of **Cell Y** to **Cell Z**.

For e.g. cell **R16** Value changed to **Approved** (via Google Form) the value of cell **Y16** at that time must be copied to **Z16** only and will not affect the entire column.

Please let me know if it can be done using some Addon or any other simple ways.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a VERY narrow, closed question - you're inviting a yes/no answer. So:

- Yes, it can be done
- an apps script is the conventional way to do it.
- trigger the script by using on OnEdit or onChange trigger.

There are many precedents/examples for this script and trigger on WebApps, and StackOverflow and elsewhere on the internet). I can't comment about an add-on (others may know).